# How to use Parceler with ArrayList<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: arraylist, parceler

I'm trying to use Parceler to transfer variable of ArrayList>, but it always give error when running, just link intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("votedetail", arrlist);. Searched and found no example, how to use it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details about the error you get. Probably it has to do with the object types you have in the `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` can't be parceled if the objects it contains are not Parcelables. As far as I know, Android SDK implementations of `Map<K,V>` do not implement `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the method's signature on [Android Developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)):

`Intent putParcelableArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`

The objects in the `ArrayList` **have to be** `Parcelable`s.
As far as I know, Android SDK implementations of `Map<K,V>` (`HashMap`, `SortedMap`, etc) do not implement `Parcelable`. You will have to write your own implementation which will also be `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0):

B0Andrew, Thank you for your help. I found the answer at last. Using putParcelableArrayList to do it. First wrap the

```
"Arraylist<Map<String, String>>"
```

to become Arraylist(new one Arraylist, then add the variable), then I can use putParcelableArrayList  to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

Parceler is a library for serializing `Parcelable` objects.  There is no need to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`, just use `putParcelable()`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> value = new ArrayList<>();
// Fill out List

intent.putParcelable("votedetail", Parcels.wrap(value));
```

And you may deserialize in the `onCreate` of the receiving activity:

```
List<Map<String, String>> value = intent.getParcelableExtra("votedetail");
```

You can find examples on how to use it directly on the website: http://parceler.org/